# Can another app register my custom url scheme

Tags: iphone, ios

I have two apps that use custom URL schemes to switch between each other. Is it possible that another app can register the same custome url scheme on a device, essentially making my app A switch erroneously to the "fake" app?

Comment: Am asking if Apple has some sort of verification process around this. Dev time may not be indicative of the delivered product

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes they can, however the first to do so "wins"

Comment: Thanks.There may be only one! :-)

Comment: Correct and seeing above comment no approval process. Just add it in Xcode.

Comment: It seems iOS called the last installed. Is it true or is there another logic ?